# How to rewrite email address address as special characters

Tags: php, laravel

I'm new in laravel. Sorry if my english is bad.

I want to ask, how to rewrite email address as special character.
3 last before '@' is character normal and the rest convert to *.

Example :
Full email address : `johndoe@gmail.com` converted : `***doe@gmail.com`

other examples :

1. `johndoe123456@gmail.com` converted : `**********456@gmail.com`
2. `johndoe123456@yahoo.com` converted : `**********456@yahoo.com`
3. `johndoe123456@hotmail.com` converted : `**********456@hotmail.com`
4. `johndoe123456@rocketmail.com` converted : `**********456@rocketmail.com`

Comment: Got any code we can work with?

Comment: pls, help to explain with your link?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/j6h4n6up/1/ - in the html block... pure php way, hope it helps.

Comment: @ZBerg Thanks a lot !